# What happens if I invest candy with Baron?

Tags: costume-quest-2

Baron is asking me to invest 200 candy with him, which is most of what I have. Is it worth it? What happens if I invest my candy?

Answer (score 1):

While it may seem expensive now, it is worth doing.

If you invest the 200 candy with Baron now, in the future you will be able to find him again in the park in Old Auburn Pines, at which point he will give you 1000 candy in return.